# add data after every 2nd element in an array

Tags: java, list, algorithm, arraylist, data-structures

I want to add object/data in an array after every 2nd element ....just for making more clear I am going to use a simple example

I have arrayList of :

```java
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("messi");
list.add("ronaldo");
list.add("rooney");
list.add("pogba");
list.add("hazard");

print(list);
//output : [messi,  ronaldo, rooney, pogba,hazard]
```

What I want is:

```java
//[messi,  ronaldo, DATA, rooney, pogba, DATA, hazard]
```

how I can achieve this.

Adding data in an array after every 2nd element.

Comment: What is stopping you from calling `add(index, value)` to add values at index 2, 5, 8, 11, ...?

Comment: @Andreas If i directly try to add `list.add(2,"Data");` it's throwing an error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 0`

Comment: @SagarGangwal Don't do that on an empty list. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63507033/5221149).

Comment: @Andreas, Yes had seen it.

Comment: @SagarGangwal Since you apparently didn't get the context of your own code, I've added your code to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63507033/5221149).

Comment: @Andreas , Mine also printing same output without using `add(index,value)` method.

Comment: If possible always try to add element using `add()` method and not with `add(index,value)` in List

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**By maintaining a counter.**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("messi");
        list.add("ronaldo");
        list.add("rooney");
        list.add("pogba");
        list.add("hazard");

        int counter = 0 ;
        List<Object> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Object obj : list){
            data.add(obj);
            counter = counter + 1;
            if(counter%2 == 0)
                data.add("DATA");
        } 
        
        for(Object obj : data)
            System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So, you can do is create a new list to store the old data with new object:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> newlist = new ArrayList<>();

list.add("messi");
list.add("ronaldo");
list.add("rooney");
list.add("pogba");
list.add("hazard");

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
   if(i%2==0) {
       // Add DATA after 2 items
       newlist.add(data);
    }
    newlist.add(list.get(i));
 }
```

Please someone format since I'm writing from my phone.

Comment: `newlist` becomes `[messi, DATA, ronaldo, rooney, DATA, pogba, hazard, DATA]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        sample.addList("messi", list);
        sample.addList("ronaldo", list);
        sample.addList("rooney", list);
        sample.addList("pogba", list);
        sample.addList("hazard", list);
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    private static void addList(String value, List<Object> objects) {
          if (!objects.isEmpty() && (objects.size() % 3 == 2)) {
            objects.add("Data");
        }
        objects.add(value);

    }
}
```

You can create one utility method as mentioned above.
For every time before adding element check that if **`list.size() % 3 == 2`** then add extra element.

This will help you.

Comment: Your output is `[messi, ronaldo, Data, rooney, Data, pogba, Data, hazard]`.

Comment: You are adding "Data" in the same list for which length you are taking divisibility by 2 into account.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the desired output and the indexes of the inserted DATA values:

```
[messi, ronaldo, DATA, rooney, pogba, DATA, hazard]
   0        1      2      3      4      5      6
```

The DATA values go in index 2, 5, 8, 11, ...

Which means it's a simple `for` loop calling [`add(int index, E element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-):

```java
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("messi");
list.add("ronaldo");
list.add("rooney");
list.add("pogba");
list.add("hazard");
System.out.println(list);

for (int i = 2; i < list.size(); i += 3) {
    list.add(i, "DATA");
}
System.out.println(list);
```

*Output*

```
[messi, ronaldo, rooney, pogba, hazard]
[messi, ronaldo, DATA, rooney, pogba, DATA, hazard]
```

Comment: If you see here https://www.baeldung.com/java-collections-complexity , time complexity of method you choose is in average runs in `O(n)` time where as add() have `takes O(1) time`

Comment: @SagarGangwal What does that have to do with the asked question?

Comment: You are enough mature to answer in optimized approach.

Comment: @SagarGangwal The question was how to *"add object/data in an array after every 2nd element"*. This is how you do that to an existing array list with data in it, i.e. this is a direct, on-point answer to the question.

Comment: That's your opinion. But optimized one should be adding an element using `O(1)` time complexity method not with `O(n)`.

Comment: @SagarGangwal Sure, and if that was a primary goal, the question should have said so. Since it isn't, this is a perfectly legitimate answer.

Comment: That should be primary goal of every developer, you are holding 1.2 lakhs + reputations and i am admiring you. I rest my case here. Once again special thanks..!!

Comment: @SagarGangwal No, writing *functioning* code is the *primary* goal of every developer. Since OP is obviously a new developer, still learning to write code, mixing in micro-optimizations will just confuse, and is counter-productive at that stage. Understand the audience. Programmers that need high-performance code would never see this, since they would already know how to do what the question asks.